# Avro in base image for all services in a Docker Swarm?? NiFi --> Kafka --> PostgreSQL

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, avro, apache-nifi

I'm new to Docker. Also new to NiFi and Kafka...

**Question:** How do I manage Avro with a Docker stack? Do I install Avro for *every* image I build in my `docker-compose.yml` file? Should I have a separate container somehow?

---

**Details:**

My vision is a 5 machine swarm running ETL processes through NiFi to Kafka (using Avro), then pulling off the messages to 3 x PostgreSQL containers w/ unique databases. Another container will run a webserver to serve access to the DBs.

So that's three containers plus three PostgreSQL container instances.

Other services/microservices can live in the existing containers or spin off into a separate container eventually (ex: API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Nifi includes all necessary libraries to read and write Avro data.

You might also want to consider using a container of the [Confluent Schema Registry](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry) for centrally managing Avro data.

NiFi has integration with the registry. Kafka doesn't care you're sending Avro to it, only the clients care how data is encoded or decoded

If you only care about Kafka, Avro, and Postgres, try using Kafka Connect's JDBC connector, then managing NiFi isn't necessary

If you do want Nifi and Kafka in respective cluster setups,   they both depend on a Zookeeper instance

Comment: This is fantastic - thanks! Sounds like I’ll add a container for the Schema Registry and for Zookeeper.

Comment: To get this final answer clearly: I would never “run” Avro as a service, just the schema registry. Avro itself would be installed anywhere I need to encode/decode, and that layer would communicate with the Schema Registry.

Comment: "Avro as a service" is the Registry, essentially. It's not required, but it allows a type of "Avro ID database" instead of embedding the schema into the Kafka record itself. (It makes your messages smaller! ;) ) Any client that needs Avro will need the avro  library in the Java classpath. The schema registry, NiFi, and confluent's Avro serde clients all provide it https://docs.confluent.io/current/app-development.html You'll also find integration with the registry for any JDBC database at https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_connector.html

Comment: The Confluent Documentation includes great resources and example containers for running all necessary components. You just need to add nifi to it. https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/tree/4.0.x/examples/cp-all-in-one